# how to add scrolling ability

Tags: java, android

i have created textviews which took the whole page and now the rest are down and to see them i have to add scrolling ability can anybody tell me how can i do it? im sorry for any disturbance im just a beginner as you may know

this is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".LinearLayout" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (من كرمت عليه نفسه هانت عليه الدنيا)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (الخير كله في صيانة الإنسان نفسه)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (ما أحب المؤمن معافى في الدنيا، وفي نفسه وماله، ولا يصاب بشيء من المصائب)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" قال (عليه السلام): (ضل من ليس له حليم يرشده، وذل من ليس له سفيه يعضده..)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (ويل لمن غلبت آحاده أعشاره)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (اللئيم يأكل ماله الأعداء، والذي خبث لا يخرج إلا نكداً..)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (إن الجسد إذا لم يمرض يأشر ولا خير في جسد يأشر..)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (عليكم بأداء الأمانة، فوالذي بعث محمداً بالحق نبياً لو أن قاتل أبي الحسين بن علي ائتمنني على السيف الذي قتله به لأديته إليه..)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (أفضل الأعمال عند الله ما عمل بالسنة)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (لقد استرقك بالود من سبقك بالشكر..)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (لا يكون الصديق صديقاً حتى يقطع لأخيه المؤمن قطعة من دينه يرقعها بالاستغفار..)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (ضمنت على ربي أنه لا يسال أحد من غير حاجة إلا اضطرته المسألة يوماً إلى أن يسأل من حاجة..)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (إياك، وما تعتذر منه)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (إن الله جل جلاله يقول: وعزتي وعظمتي وجمالي، وبهائي، وعلوي، وارتفاع مكان لا يؤثر عبد هواي على هواه إلا جعلت همه في آخرته، وغناه في قلبه، كففت عنه ضيعته، وضمنت السماوات والأرض رزقه، وأتته الدنيا وهي راغمة)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap them in a [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). [Here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/scrollview/android-scrollview-example/) is an example.

Comment: Yeps. ScrollView is what OP wants.